# Convert decimal to string with at least a zero for integer value in C#

Tags: c#, type-conversion, decimal, cultureinfo

I try to figure out how I can convert to strings the values with decimal type of these Account1, Account2, Account3 with at least one zero after the decimal separator for integer values.

```
Person person = new()
{
    Name = "Tom",
    Account1 = 1m,
    Account2 = 0.2m,
    Account3 = 0.003m
};

var props = person.GetType().GetProperties();
foreach (var prop in props)
{
    var value = prop.GetValue(person);
    if (value?.GetType() == typeof(decimal))
    {
        decimal casted_value = (decimal)value;
        Console.WriteLine(casted_value.ToString("0.0#", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));
    }
}

class Person
{
    public string? Name { get; set; }
    public decimal Account1 { get; set; }
    public decimal Account2 { get; set; }
    public decimal Account3 { get; set; }
}
```

Current output:

```
1.0
0.2
0.0 // Expected: 0.03 => so I should add a "#" to "0.0#" but what if the account value is 0.0004? ... same issue...
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You cannot expect to display 0.03 when the value is 0.003. That would mean multiplying the value by some power of 10.

Comment: You can use the [standard numeric format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-numeric-format-strings) for this, either use *F*, *N* or *G*, depending on your needs, e.g. `Console.WriteLine(casted_value.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` will always produce exactly two decimal places.

Comment: I think this is a little unclear. Can you confirm or correct: 1 => "1.0", 0.1 => "0.1" , 0.0123 => "0.01" , 0.00358 => "0.003" is what you want?

Comment: You need to include # characters for as many decimal places as you might want to display.

Comment: To clarify what I need: I need to display one zero after the decimal separator for integers and if it is a float, display the exact float without any limitation "1 => 1.0" and "0.123456789 => 0.123456789"

Comment: @Fildor: no, I want to display the full decimal number 0.00358 (I don't want it to truncate or round it)

Comment: @jmcilhinney: So in your opinion I should add as many "#" as number after the decimal separator... is there no way to perform this automatically?

Comment: @Frankie Does `if (q == Math.Truncate(q)) { /* write it with ".0" appended */} else { /* write it normally */}` do what you want?

Comment: Having both is kind of hard. Not aware of an "_at least_ n digits, pad with 0" format modifier.

Comment: Yes. You can have an arbitrary number of digits after the decimal point but you can't force a specific  minimum with the same format specifier. You either need a specific number of optional decimal places or else use two separate format specifers.